# How can I determine whether GPS is available? Also, how can I determine city/state/country based on GPS coordinates?

Tags: android, gps

I have a few little questions regarding GPS in Android:

1. How can I determine whether GPS is available on the device?
2. I found several links for determining the coordinates of the current location. Is there any way to determine the city/state/country based on these coordinates?

Comment: You should take a few seconds to re-read what you post. Even if english isn't your first language, you should avoid spelling errors such as `GSP`

Comment: Its just mark I haven't seen, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your first question. You can try to get a certain `LocationProvider` by calling the [getProvider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProvider%28java.lang.String%29) method of the `LocationManager`. If the requested provider is available it returns the LocationProvider if not it returns null.

Your second question. Yes you can do that with the [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). By calling the [getFromLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation) method and passing it the latitude, longitude and a value for the maximum addresses you'd like to obtain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have a device now, so I'll tell the results tomorrow :)

Comment: I think I've found better way to check ability of provider: locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Comment: @davs: watch out this only returns if the given provider is enabled in the settings not if it is available.